# I need to put a div OVER a scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I have a tumblr theme I am working with where there's a scroll-overflow container, and a div for pagination that overlaps. But the scrollbar of that div interrupts the pagination link, going over it instead of under. What is the best way to put the scrollbar BEHIND the top layer pagination div?

[Example here](http://themesbyoctomoosey.tumblr.com/theme57)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using absolute positioning, why not make the pagination div a sibling of the container, and use:

```
#pagif {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 270px)
}
```

I tested on the example and it stays at the same place as before, but now it's above the container.

Please check this [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wmYqpb)